# JSONDecoderError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I want to read a json file in my code, here is my code:

```
import json

    with open("video_easy_X101.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        annotation = json.load(f)
    print(annotation.keys())
    return annotation
```

the problem I met is json.load(f), here is the error message:

```
File "/data/users/zoey0527/fbsource/fbcode/buck-out/dev/gen/mobile-vision/experimental/body_2d/scripts/predictor#link-tree/mobile-vision/experimental/body_2d/scripts/predictor.py", line 74, in main
    annotation = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/local/fbcode/platform007/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/fbcode/platform007/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/fbcode/platform007/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/fbcode/platform007/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like your JSON is invalid. Could you add a snippet to your post?

Comment: thanks, it looks like that the json file is wrong. I change to a new json file and this problem solved.